# Netsuite Suitetalk API and PHP Toolkit - Customer Search with Two Filters

Tags: php, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm trying to search with NetSuite SuiteTalk API using the PHP Toolkit.

The search works if I only use one filter - email, but returns an error when I add the subsidiary filter (the parts that are commented out).

```
<?php

require_once '..\PHPToolkit\NetSuiteService.php';

$netsuiteService = new NetSuiteService();

$emailSearch = new SearchStringField();
$emailSearch->operator = "is";
$emailSearch->searchValue = "testing@gmail.com";

//$subsidiarySearch = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
//$subsidiarySearch->searchValue = [1];
//$subsidiarySearch->operator = 'anyOf';

$search = new CustomerSearchBasic();
$search->email = $emailSearch;
//$search->subsidiary =$subsidiarySearch;

$searchRequest = new searchRequest();
$searchRequest->searchRecord =$search;

$searchResponse = $netsuiteService->search($searchRequest);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsidiary is not an enum. Use SearchMultiSelect.

The search value will be a RecordRef.

Create the RecordRef first, then assign it to the searchValue of the multiSelect.